# Is LNET components blocking or non-blocking?

Tags: blocking, nonblocking, lan, lazarus, freepascal

I am looking to use LNET components for LAN communication and would like to know if they are blocking or non-blocking by default. Apparently, there seems to be no option to select from for the component.